# Viewshed only faces one direction

Tags: qgis, viewshed

I am working with qgis 3.16.10, when I perform a viewshed it creates an arc that faces one direction from my viewing location. Every example I see online does this as well, I am calculating the view from the top of a hill and expected a roughly 360 degree view. Why is it a 180 degree arc on one side of my location?[image: my viewshed tool and parameters][image: the results of my viewshed as you can see it seems to be a 90 degree arc]

Comment: Without further information, it's difficult to give any advice. Add more details to your question, including which tool you use to create the viewshed and probably also a screenshot of the settings you make.

Comment: Is that possible that your observer point is with its 'back against a wall' and therefore, it places half the space into pure shadow?

Comment: Try raising your "Viewing elevation above ground" to 100M or even 1000M to check whether @swiss_knight has identified your problem.